# Searching Google in Firefox causes a download dialog

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, google-search

Searching Google in Firefox causes a download dialog which detected **JSon Activity** !

It happens several times and interrupts my typing.

[image]
I disabled half of my addons that I thought were suspicious. I also upgraded my FF to version 12.0 (current) — no difference.

Comment: How about disabling FlashGot? Or running Firefox in [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode) to disable all plugins temporarily?

Comment: Hi, I didn't try safe mode, think it shouldn't appear on that, cause every feature is disabled :D, but I disabled flashgot with no luck

Comment: Try it. Note this is the browser safe mode, not the operating system safe mode. It will help narrow down if it's an addon causing the issue or a browser misconfiguration somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could either be caused by a malfunctioning extension or a browser misconfiguration. The way to find out is to try running the browser in [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode) - note this is not your operating system's safe mode.

If safe mode still exhibits this problem, it's a misconfiguration of how Firefox handles MIME types, or at least this specific one.

#### Reset all MIME type handlers:

> 1. Type [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) into the address bar.
> 2. Find the preference browser.download.pluginOverrideTypes and, if it is present, right-click on it and select reset.
> 3. Find the preference plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types and, if it is present, right-click on it and select reset.
> 4. Open the profile folder. (The profile folder is hidden by default in Windows 7/Vista/XP/2000 and Linux; read [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) for help finding it).
>    Note: [In Firefox 3.6 and above you can open the profile folder from the Firefox menu, via "Help -> Troubleshooting Information".](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Using_the_Help_menu_-_Firefox_3.6_and_above)
> 5. [Completely close your Mozilla browser.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Kill_application)
> 6. Delete (or rename) the file [mimeTypes.rdf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf). Caution: There is also a mimeTypes.rdf file in the [program folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installation_directory). Do not delete it by mistake.

[More information (source)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions)

Comment: Thanks Bob, I myself guessed it should be related to browser config or addons as you said, you give a comprehensive info on this and this is appreciated, I will try playing with that considering your provided information